# Apply qcut for complete dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the column values with bin numbers based on quantiles but for each and every column present in the dataframe.

I know how to do this with qcut and labels as its parameter for a single column, but do not know whether it can be applied for complete dataframe or not.
say the dataframe looks like below..

```
    ID  CC  DD  EE
0   Q1  0   23  18
1   Q2  2   32  19
2   Q3  3   45  20
3   Q4  4   54  21
4   Q5  5   67  22
5   Q6  6   76  23
```

The ID column should remain unchanged but the other columns should be replaced by bin numbers, like below..

```
    ID  CC  DD  EE
0   Q1  1   1   1
1   Q2  2   2   1
2   Q3  3   2   2
3   Q4  4   3   3
4   Q5  5   4   4
5   Q6  5   5   5
```

the bin numbers I have provided here for CC, DD, EE are not exact and for understanding purpose only.

And in the real dataset, there are more than 100 columns and 1000 rows, and I do not want to replace the 'ID' column, but all the other columns.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use pandas.cut()

```
import pandas as pd

df['CC'] = pd.cut(df['CC'], [0, 5, 10,20])
```

Similarly you can do for other columns as well.

Comment: First thing, I want to do qcut, because I want percentile wise bin, and second thing, I want to know whether it is possible to do qcut on the whole dataset except the first column.

Comment: So to do in that way. You can use 'percentile' parameter inside the 'describe()'. Then you get the values of percentiles what you want and then apply on the column as is. ```df['CC'] = pd.cut(df['CC'], [0, 5, 10,20])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.cut() for a number of fractions as well. like this

```
pd.cut(df['CC'], 8).head()
```

```
0    (13.626, 15.833]
1     (11.42, 13.626]
2      (4.8, 7.00665]
3      (9.213, 11.42]
4     (11.42, 13.626]
Name: normal, dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [(0.369, 2.593] < (2.593, 4.8] < (4.8, 7.00665] < (7.00665, 9.213] < (9.213, 11.42] < (11.42, 13.626] < (13.626, 15.833] < (15.833, 18.0397]]
```

Comment: but how would you do that for a whole data frame as a function? parse to apply qcut for each column ?